# /sbin/zsysd using extreme amount of CPU+memory

Tags: crash, 20.10, memory-usage, zfs, cpu-load

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy with full-disk encryption, on a Thinkpad T490. I did a fully clean install (moving from Debian) of Ubuntu about a month ago.
After boot `/sbin/zsysd` starts using large amounts of CPU+memory, I attached a screenshot showing what it does directly after logging in, but this isn't limited to just after login, it keeps like this and occasionally crashes my laptop because its usage increases.

I just rebooted it because it literally was using all 8 of my cores at 100% and used my full RAM+SWAP. I had htop open but couldn't take a screenshot because my laptop didn't react.

What could it be doing, and how do I fix this?

Screenshot after login:[image: screenshot-after-login]

Comment: Are you using ZFS ? Then maybe this bug is an explanation: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zsys/+bug/1870461

Comment: @SorenA Yes I'm using ZFS, that bug seems to be quite similar to what I see, but it appears to have been fixed in zsys 0.5.0, I am running 0.5.2.. Disabling zsysd seemed to work but if it didn't, I'll fill a new bug-report